# Difference between Single Document Interface and Multi Document Interface

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

What is the difference between Single Document Interface and Multi Document Interface in MFC? When and where we are using it? In which type of application we can use them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Single Document Interface (SDI) is a document-oriented application, which provides exactly one document space (like Notepad).

Multi Document Interface (MDI) allows to have several (also different typed) documents to be open (so provides a "Windows" menu).

Both use the document-view pattern.